# What is the significance of Min and Max in below python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why the min and max is used in the below function

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    round = lambda x: min(255, max(x, 0))
    return ("{:02X}" * 3).format(round(r), round(g), round(b))
```

Comment: In my opinion this is not Python-related; this is a standard-construct to ensure, the value is between 0 and 255 (including). Values out of this interval are dragged to the respective boundary.

Comment: It's just clipping the value to between 0 and 255, inclusive.  Values less than 0 are clipped to 0, and values greater than 255 are clipped to 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the possible range of the values `r, g, b` is in 0 - 255, `max(x, 0)` is to prevent the value to drop below 0 and `min(255, max(x, 0))` is to prevent the value to go above 255.

Example: if r = -20, max(r, 0) = max(-20, 0) = 0
and if r = 280, max(255, min(r, 0)) = max(255, min(280, 0)) = max(255, 0) = 255.

[Graph for reference](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/snjkl627us)